# Clojure: how to avoid eval-ing the not-found expression in map get

Tags: clojure

I have a map called `robots`. While looking up the map, if a robot by the given key does not exist I want to create one. [`clojure.core/get`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/get) with the `not-found` arg seems like exactly what I need.

However, it seems that the `not-found` expression is evaluated eagerly. How can I prevent this evaluation so that I create a new robot only if one does not exist?

```
robot> (def robots {1 {:name "R2D2"}})
#'robot/robots


robot> (get robots 1)
{:name "R2D2"}

robot> (get robots 1 (println "damn it"))
damn it
{:name "R2D2"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fully agree with [Timothy Dean's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23197975/1202461), but his implementation won't work if you have false or nil values in your map.

Here is more accurate solution:

```
(if (contains? robots 1)
  (get robots 1)
  (println "Beep boop"))
```

And the fancy macro:

```
(defmacro get-lazy [map key not-found]
  `(let [map# ~map
         key# ~key]
    (if (contains? map# key#)
      (get map# key#)
      ~not-found)))
```

I'm using `let` to eliminate the possibility of causing some side-effect twice, e.g.:

```
(get-lazy {1 false}
          (do (println "Side effect") 1)
          (println "Oops!"))
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that this isn't a branching statement -- it actually expects a value, not a form or function, in the `not-found` slot. So you could use a branching statement:

```
(if-let [r (get robots 1)] r (println "Beep boop"))
```

If that's too much typing, you could get fancy:

```
(defmacro get-lazy
  [map idx statement]
  `(if-let [v# (get ~map ~idx)] v# ~statement))

user=> (get-lazy robots 1 (println "Oops!"))
{:name "R2D2"}
```

Following tips from A.Webb's comments, we arrive at the following macro. It uses the same method as above, and it can also handle maps containing `false` and `nil` values. It's also faster than calling both `contains?` and `get` on the map. Instead of using a false return value (false/nil) to tip you off that the item isn't present, use the built-in functionality of `get` and check for something that would never occur in a "wild" map.

```
(defmacro get-lazy
 [map idx statement]
 `(let [r# (get ~map ~idx ~::nil)]
    (if (identical? r# ~::nil) ~statement r#)))

user=> (get-lazy {:idx 8} :idx (println "Yo."))
8
user=> (get-lazy {:coconuts :migration} :swallow (println "Who goes there?"))
Who goes there?
user=> (ns another.ns)
another.ns=> (user/get-lazy {:LUE ::nil} :LUE (println "42."))
:another.ns/nil
```

You could eschew the macro and go the functional route:

```
(let [sentinel ::nil]
  (defn lazyget
   [map idx function]
   (let [r (get map idx sentinel)]
      (if (identical? r sentinel) (function) r))))
```

This is a little slower on my machine.

Comment: Thanks. For my use-case this would work fine. As a general case, [@Leonid's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23198238/117750) will be a better choice. For posterity, I'll select that as the "correct" one.

Comment: I prefer this one as it avoids traversing the map twice (contains? then get).

Comment: You can create values that _can't_ be in your map as your not-found sentinel: `(let [sentinel (Object.)] (let [r (get robots 1 sentinel)] (if (= r sentinel) (println "doh!") r)))` But you can also generally use namespaced keywords `::not-found` to create not-found values that wouldn't be in legit maps.

Comment: In my tests, the `contains?` call doesn't actually add much (if any) overhead over my original formulation. The docs claim `contains?` is constant/logarithmic. And though I expected the second formulation to be just as fast, I find it's twice as slow as Leonid's solution.

Comment: Yes, `contains?` and `get` are essentially constant-time for a hash-map. Relative performance should depend in part on whether you are testing success or failure cases [and also the size of the map ("constant" time does not mean same time here, just practically bounded by a small constant)]. In Beschastny's failure of `contains?` goes immediately to the false clause where success requires a `get`. In the second formulation here failure has to be confirmed with the equality check. The second formulation should replace `=` with `identical?` to speed up that check.

Comment: I bench `bar` being faster than `foo` when mixing equal number of successes and failures, where `bar` is the patched up second formulation `(let [sentinel (Object.)] (defn bar [m k f] (let [r (get m k sentinel)] (if (identical? r sentinel) (f) r))))` and `foo` being `(defn foo [m k f] (if (contains? m k) (get m k) (f)))`.